# String concatenation in vertical matrix in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have a vertical matrix like

```
names = {
11
22
33
44
55
}
```

and I want to concatenate same string to all like

```
names = {
11nere
22nere
33nere
44nere
55nere
}
```

how could I do it in matlab?

Comment: Given your brackets, you actually have a `cell` array. Also you need to specify if the entries are numerical or strings - the way you've written it they appear to be numerical. See my answer(s) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one liner should do it

```
names = cellfun(@(x)[num2str(x), 'nere'], names, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

where I've assumed the `names` cell array contains numeric entries not strings to start with - otherwise it's even simpler,

```
names = cellfun(@(x)[x, 'nere'], names, 'uniformoutput', false);
```